Malloc sometimes fails immediately after a free
I want to test my code in low memory situations.
I wrote this function with setrlimit to limit the available memory :
unsigned short int oom_enable = 0;
char* _oomfill = NULL;

uint32_t oom_setup(uint32_t ramlimit)
{
    struct rlimit limit;

    /* Limit available RAM to 64MB for all suites/testcase/process/fork */
    /* to test OOM without exhausting the system's resources */
    limit.rlim_cur = ramlimit;
    limit.rlim_max = limit.rlim_cur;
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr,_("setrlimit() failed with errno=%d %s\n"), errno,strerror(errno));
        /* Better to abort than to permit RAM bombing */
        abort();
    }
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit) != 0) {
        fprintf (stderr,_("getrlimit() failed with errno=%d %s\n"), errno,strerror(errno));
        /* Better to abort than to potentially permit RAM bombing */
        abort();
    }
    return limit.rlim_cur;
}

Then, I call it at the begining of my program :
    /* Limit available RAM to 64MB for all suites/testcase/process/fork */
    /* to test OOM without exhausting the system's resources */
    ramlimit=64*1024*1024;
    printf ("Limit memory usage to %uMB : ",ramlimit/1024/1024);
    ramlimit = oom_setup(ramlimit);
    printf ("%uB (%uMB)\n",ramlimit,ramlimit/1024/1024);

Then, I have 2 macros, one to eat most of the memory immediately before running the function under test :
 * After this call, there is AT MOST (KB*1024) bytes  available but probably
 * less. This has to be called immediately before the function under test.
 * Nothing else can be executed, printf, assertions, ....  */
#define OOMTEST_BEGIN(KB) \
    if (1==oom_enable) { \
        struct rlimit limit; \
        uint32_t min,cur,max; \
        if (NULL!=_oomfill) { \
            free(_oomfill); \
            _oomfill = NULL; \
        } \
        if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit) != 0) { \
            fprintf (stderr,_("getrlimit() failed with errno=%d %s\n"), errno,strerror(errno)); \
            abort(); \
        } \
        min = 0; \
        cur = 0; \
        max = limit.rlim_cur; \
        while ((max-min)>(KB*1024)) { \
            if (NULL!=_oomfill) \
                free(_oomfill); \
            cur = ((min+max)/2); \
            if (NULL==(_oomfill = malloc(cur))) { \
                max = cur; \
            } else { \
                min = cur; \
            } \
        } \
        fprintf(stderr,"OOM Test, consummed %u bytes.\n",cur); \
        /* Keep some minimal headroom (10B) for tooling */ \
        free(_oomfill); \
        if (NULL == (_oomfill=malloc(cur-10))) { \
            fprintf(stderr,_("OOM failed to keep headroom RAM.\n")); \
            abort(); \
        } \
        _oomfill[0]=1; \
    }

And the other to free the memory immediately after the function under test :
/** Free the RAM consumed by OOMTEST_BEGIN
 *
 * This has to be called IMMEDIATELY after the function under testing, BEFORE
 * any check, test, assertion, output of the results. */
#define OOMTEST_END \
    if (1==oom_enable) { \
        if (NULL!=_oomfill) { \
            free(_oomfill); \
            _oomfill = NULL; \
            malloc_trim(0); \
            /* SW barrier (compiler only) */ \
            __asm__ volatile("": : :"memory"); \
            /* HW barrier (CPU instruction) */ \
            __sync_synchronize(); \
        } \
    }

My test code looks like :
    size_t result;

    /* This function will trigger getblocksize when memtrack is still not initialized to test autoinit */
    OOMTEST_BEGIN(0.01);
    result=memtrack_getblocksize(NULL);
    OOMTEST_END;

    /* Check expected results */
    ck_assert_msg(0==result,"Blocksize of NULL pointer should be 0");

Everything works as expected, but sometimes The code stops at abort(), when _oomfill is cur bytes long, filling the whole RAM, if freeed, after the malloc(cur-10) attempt.
Basically, I try to malloc(fullRAM-10) after free(fullRAM). I works most of the time, but not in some situations. It is very difficult to debug in gdb/ddd and I would appreciate help or clues.
Edit: I tried to use realloc instead of free/malloc, same result.
Edit: It was a bug in the logic : if malloc(cur) fails in the loop, max takes cur value and cur for the next iteration. But if max-min is below the required threshold, there is no "next iteration", _oomfill is NULL, and.... cur can be more than the available RAM, failing to malloc(cur-10). My fix, despite not perfect (could theorically loop forever) was to change the while condition :
while ((NULL==_oomfill)||((max-min)>(threshold)))

Thus, even if max-min fullfil the threshold constraint, the loop will continue to iterate until findind a valid value for cur.

Unrelated: When you print uint32_ts, don't use %u, use PRIu32.

François Cerbelle, Using floating-point instead of integer math seems dodgy.  Consider only using size_t for size calculations.

Why aren't you using functions or at least static inline functions instead of the enormous macros?

malloc(cur-10) is a bit scary should cur < 10 as cur is an unsigned type.

"It is very difficult to debug in gbd/ddd" --> replace macros with functions.

I don't see any content in your macros that requires them to be macros rather than functions!!!  You should almost never write a macro where a function can be used.

Why do you think you need memory barriers? Is this using threads?

@François Cerbelle, when malloc(cur - 10) or malloc(fullRAM-10) fails, what is the value of fullRAM or cur?

@chux-ReinstateMonica

Initially, I wanted to specify the amount in KB, hence the floating point calculation. Not the best, I agree, I'll update my code.
I set rlimit to 64MB by default in my unit-tests and the cur value is around this boundary :
OOM Test, consummed 63016936 bytes.
OOM Test, consummed 63016936 bytes.
OOM Test, consummed 62889960 bytes.
As expected, and far-away from the 10 bytes headroom (cur-10) cur is always >>10


@JonathanLeffler
@chux-ReinstateMonica
@Kaz
I use macro to make the debugging code less impacting the results. a function would make a call, thus a stack usage. I'm unsure about static inline
@Kaz
I'm using "check" (libcheck) as a testing framework, which can fork testcases. Given that the rlimit is set at the global parent process, I can use forks, not threads.
I added barriers because I thought that free was lazy and did not actually freed the RAM, makeing the malloc fail.

Can you simplify the code, remove macros, and post the source code to a full compilable program ?

@JonathanLeffler "static inline" would need an exception in the compiler args (-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -ansi)

@chqrlie I did one, not posted, but I did not manager to trigger the failure, thus I did not post it

I switched to size_t everywhere
I switched to functions (not static, not inline because of -ansi)
Problem still occurs

@FrançoisCerbelle: you should not be compiling to the C90 standard, which is what -ansi means.  The world has changed a lot in the last 30 years; so has the C Standard.

@JonathanLeffler I use the most restrictive and constraining standards (and cppcheck flags) to implement my code, then, if needed (func, network, ....), I relax the checking either with inline pragma or, with specific AM_CFLAGS. This catches a lot of mistakes.
From your point of view, is there any drawback doing this way ?

@FrançoisCerbelle: in many ways, C90 is the least constraining standard; you are allowed all sorts of liberties with function declarations and definitions.  OTOH, there are lots of things you can't do in it that are valid in later standards.  I suppose you need to decide on your targets and compile accordingly.  C90 is no longer relevant to me; YMMV.  I mostly work to C11 (effectively C18 too).  Since there isn't a C23 standard published yet, it is a bit premature for me to use it, much as I'd like to.

setrlimit(RLIMIT_AS, &limit) doesn't only set the limit of the returned memory from malloc, but limits all the address space used by the program, including malloc overhead. To understand why malloc fails in your case, you really have to dig into the source code of the implementation you are using.
Calling malloc(cur - 10); after calling foo = malloc(cur); free(foo); may fail for any of (but not limited to) the following reasons:

malloc may, for any reason, ask for additional memory from the  OS to increase its memory pool, and fail.

malloc may want to give you more memory than you asked for.

It may chose to use more overhead than previous calls to malloc

To prevent fragmentation, blocks of size cur - 10 may be allocated from another memory pool than blocks of size cur, and there is no more free memory in that pool.



I want to unit-test behavior in OOM scenarios to cover all the error management code also. Hence I setrlimit to a value, then I eat all the RAM I can (within rlimit to avoid swap) until I have less than a threshold between a success malloc and a fail malloc. I know that I have between 0 and threshold available. I do not want to have 0, the test would fail outside of the function to test, thus, I free the allocated RAM and allocate less.
I'll try another path with realloc which sould be a better way in my case, it should not free/malloc in this case and should succeed

Sorry, it was a bug in my while logic. Thank you for you help, your answer was useful and I learnt from it.

One possible explanation is malloc may use different allocation strategies when you pass certain thresholds: it might be possible to allocate exactly 128KB (131072 bytes) because malloc uses memory mapping for sizes greater or equal to this threshold, and yet fail to allocate 131071 or even 131056 bytes because the overhead for arena based allocation may cause the system limit to be reached for this alternative path.
On systems using the GNU libc, this threshold can be customized using the M_MMAP_THRESHOLD environment variable.
You can further customize the GNU allocator via environment variables described here.
Also notice that your approach limits the maximum number of pages to map for the process, which interacts in subtle ways with the memory allocation routines: mapping threshold but also fragmentation may cause more memory pages to be required for some allocations than strictly necessary.
Depending on the allocation strategy, fragmentation can cause allocation failures if the required block length cannot be found in a sparse arena with small blocks distributed in an adverse fashion.

I did not manage to isolate the failure in a simple stripped down source code. I suspect that the libcheck testing framework has side effects, despite I disable forking.

Sorry, it was a bug in my while logic. Thank you for you help, your answer was useful and I learnt from it.
